PHP8.4環境で、「㎡」などの文字がmb_convert_encodingで文字化けする
<?php
echo mb_convert_encoding('㎡' ,"shift-jis", "euc-jp");

上記PHPコードを、「文字コード：EUC-JP」として保存し、「mb_internal_encoding：EUC-JP」のサーバーにて実行しました。その結果が下記でした。
PHP 7.2.34
「㎡」
PHP 8.4.2
「?」
shift-jisのエンコードでも「㎡」と表示されることを期待していましたが、「PHP 8.4.2」ではその期待通りに動作しませんでした。
従来と振る舞いが変わっている点が仕様変更か、もしくはバグなのかを知りたいです。

この辺の記事で調べていることを参考にEUC-JPが絡むとどうなるか等試してみてはどうでしょう？ PHP7.1～7.4でSJIS-winの文字列をmb_splitに渡すと失敗する現象について, PHP 8.1以降のmb_convert_encodingなどでSJISに変換するとバグる文字がある, PHPのSJIS系文字エンコーディングとエイリアスを表にまとめてみた, PHPでmb_convert_encodingを使って ㈱ をSJISに変換したら?になったのなんで？

貴重な情報有難うございます。感謝いたします。
「eucJP-win⇒SJIS-win」のエンコード指定へ修正すれば本件の文字化けは解消できる見込みではあるのですが、まずは原因解明をできればと考えご相談いたしました。
https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/6402/commits/79e8c238be0e58b441530d9194526bd39fbc908a
「Reject otherwise valid kuten codes which don't map to anything in JIS X 0208」
上記のコメントから仕様変更によるものかと想像しました。
コードレベルでは、上記コミット内の「mbfl_filt_ident_sjis」メソッドの制御に影響を受けているかと感じています。
具体的には下記制御の追加が怪しいと見ているのですが、確証がもてず。
https://github.com/alexdowad/php-src/blob/79e8c238be0e58b441530d9194526bd39fbc908a/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_sjis.c#L280
詳しい方のご意見を伺えると幸いです。

macOSのcotEditorでは㎡はeuc-jpに変換できませんでした。PythonやRubyでもエラーになります。Windows秀丸では変換できます。UnicodeコンソーシアムのJIS X 0208との変換表 https://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/OBSOLETE/EASTASIA/JIS/JIS0208.TXT にU+33A1 の記載がありません。ここまでが事実でここから推測です。PHPもUnicodeコンソーシアムの変換表に則るように なった ために起こっているのではないでしようか(確証も調べる気もないのでコメントで)

こんな記事が何か情報を探るための参考になるかもしれませんね。非公式 PHP 8.1のmbstringアップグレードガイド

皆様、コメントにて有益な回答有難うございます。
ご教示頂いた情報を少しづつ理解し「現状のPHPの振る舞いがあるべき姿で、コード側を見直すべきであろう」と私の中で整理ができてきました。
感謝いたします。
また「互換性がない振る舞いの変更があった」旨について、php-src側へも確認を仰いだところ
コミッターの方からも「㎡ is not contain JIS X 0208」との認識を回答頂きました。
https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/17238
現状のPHPの挙動に合わせて実装を見直していきたいと思います。
有難うございました。
